# Bootstrap menu doesnt work on mobile in some pages

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm working on a kinda simple website and noticed one issue in mobile mode. In my index page and couple of others the menu doesnt load, however in other pages of the same site, the menu loads properly.

They all have the same scripts and css files so I'm kinda lost.

This is the site in question: www.dulcementeperu.com

The menu only opens in dulcementeperu.com/packs and dulcementeperu.com/comprar but not on the rest.

This is the nav that's supposed to load:

```
<nav>
  <div align="center">
    <ul class="sf-menu">
      <li class="current selectedLava"><a href="/">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="packs">Packs</a></li>
      <li><a href="delivery">Delivery</a></li>
      <li><a href="comprar">Comprar</a></li>
    </ul>
    <!-- end menu -->
  </div>
</nav>
```

And this is the list of scripts the page loads:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/theme20.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.prettyPhoto.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.flexslider-min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.nicescroll.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/gmap3.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/twitter/jquery.tweet.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/custom.js"></script>
```

Any insight would be appreciated, and sorry if my english is kinda broken since it's not my native language.

Comment: Try commenting theme20.js & see if it works cos on clicking menu icon it shows error on console  http://imgur.com/a/nLB43

Comment: Try to fix console errors if it works

Comment: I think you are missing the <div id="frame_"> right after body on those pages. Because in the working pages they have that div.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the `<div id="frame_">` right before the `<div id="layout" class="full">` that should work. I think the menu works by toggling the #frame_

Comment: Yes, that was apparently the error. Thank you very much for your input.

Comment: Happy to help you.

Answer (score 0):

```html
 - please Change the z-index in  .snap-drawer-left class
and aslo Check error in  Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null
```

```
.snap-drawer-left{
    z-index: 99;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you just missed  I notice all of working page has it

```
<div id="frame_">
  // content here
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, that was apparently the error. Thank you very much for your input.

Answer (score 0):

input this code.

```
<div id="frame_"> here! </div>
```

Comment: Yes, that was apparently the error. Thank you very much for your input.